# Using the new Vista Thread Pool API in a DLL also loaded in XP (thread pool code not used in XP)

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, dll, threadpool

We are producing a DLL that is targeted at both Windows 7 and XP. We want our DLL to use the newer Vista Thread Pool API when the DLL is loaded on a Windows 7 system and not when it is loaded on an XP system.

Right now, we tried compiling the DLL with runtime detection of the OS to make sure the Vista API is never used on an XP system, but we still cannot register our DLL on a Windows XP system because of a missing dependency in kernel32.dll...

Is there a way around this other than building two separate versions of the DLL?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why don't you dynamically load kernel32.dll using LoadLibrary and then use GetProcAddress to determine if the Vista Thread Pool API functions you need are available? If they are, fine, if they are not fall back to the older API functions.

E.g. (untested)

```
typedef PTP_WAIT (WINAPI *FnCreateThreadpoolWait) (PTP_WAIT_CALLBACK,PVOID,
                                                   PTP_CALLBACK_ENVIRON);
HMODULE hLibrary;
FnCreateThreadpoolWait pFn;

hLibrary = ::LoadLibrary ("kernel32.dll");
pFn = (FnCreateThreadpoolWait) ::GetProcAddress (hLibrary,"CreateThreadpoolWait");
if (pFn == NULL) // Vista API not available
   .....
```

Comment: Because from MSDN: "Delay loading Kernel32.dll is not supported. This DLL is necessary for the delay-load helper routines to perform the delay loading." ref:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yx1x886y.aspx

Comment: I guess I don't properly understand what delay loading means then... I thought delay loading and dynamic loading were the same. Can you instruct me on what are the differences between those two concepts?

Comment: Here's a explanation of dynamic loading and delayed loading. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic-link_library#Delayed_loading. I'm not sure I'd use delayed loading in any situation. Better to use dynamic loading where you have full control and there is no need to do runtime detection of the OS.

Comment: What I tend to do where API's are not available in older OS's is use an abstract class and implement it for both the new and old API. This way you can hide the details of which API you're using. So in your case, you'd have an abstract class ThreadPoolBase and implementations ThreadPoolVista and ThreadPoolXP. You first try to instantiate ThreadPoolVista and in the constructor it dynamically loads kernel32.dll and checks for the new API. If the new API functions cannot be found, the ThreadPoolVista constructor throws an exception which when caught causes an instantiation of ThreadPoolXP.

Comment: @franmon: Delay-loading of specific functions in kernel32.dll is possible by using two imports of kernel32 in the calling DLL. This requires some post-build magic to set up as the tools won't do it.

Comment: @rushman Thanks rushman for all your explanations. It took me a little time to absorb this information, but now it is clear in my head how to  apply this to my situation. Instead of calling the API functions directly in my code, I use function pointers to those API calls if they are available. That way, I should not have any "register time" dependency on any specific version of kernel32.dll and will be able to proceed to my OS detection in the constructor of my class. Thanks a lot!